# NSIS xml::SaveFile removes xml-stylesheet declaration

Tags: xml, plugins, nsis

I am using this plugin https://nsis.sourceforge.io/XML_plug-in. However, I found out after `xml::SaveFile`, `xml-stylesheet` is removed from the xml.
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="HHConfig.xslt"?>` to `<?xml ?>`.

I am looking for the solution in internet. However, I only found this:
http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?p=3148904 but no solution for it.

> Don't remove "xml-stylesheet" declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/XML_plug-in This plugin does not support xml-stylesheet. Thus, when call xml::load, it does not load `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="HHConfig.xslt"?>`. The source code of the plugin can be modified to load it.